# Undefined when displaying data

Tags: angular

When I want to display data as a result, I get **undefined**.

This only happens with the **progress** array.

There is no such problem with the rest of the data.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**console.log(this.splineChart)**

```
[{…}]
  0:
   data: Array(1)
     0: Array(2)
       0: undefined
       1: undefined
```

ts:

```
  user: User[];
  splineChart = [];

  load() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          (params: Params) => {
            if (params['id']) {
              return this._peopleService.getPeopleById(params['id'])
            }
            return of(null)
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe(
        (user: User[]) => {
          this.splineChart = [{
            data: user.map(function (item) {
              return [item.progress.tasks, item.progress.week]; 
          })}]
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
  }
```

My json file::

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fname": "Tommie",
            "lname": "Shurtleff",
            "photo": "tommie",
            "money": "667.16",
            "progress": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "week": 1,
                    "tasks": 29
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how you are displaying data?

Comment: @VivekJain I am currently displaying via `console.log(this.splineChart)`

Comment: And in `user: User[]` what is coming?

Comment: progress is an array and you are treating it as object. `item.progress.tasks` this won't work for array. please let me know what's you are expecting so i can help you.

Comment: @VivekJain I want to display the progress data for a specific user in a chart, but first I want them to at least be displayed in the console.log().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress is an array and you are treating it as object. `item.progress.tasks` this won't work for array.

You have to loop through `item.progress` get desire result.

Replace you subscription part with below.

```
this.splineChart = [{
   data: user.map(function(item) {
     return item.progress.map(progress => [progress.tasks, progress.week]);
   })
}];
```

See below as an example.

```js
const user = [{
  "id": 1,
  "fname": "Tommie",
  "lname": "Shurtleff",
  "photo": "tommie",
  "money": "667.16",
  "progress": [{
      "id": 1,
      "week": 1,
      "tasks": 29
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "week": 2,
      "tasks": 30
    },
  ]
}];

let splineChart;
this.splineChart = [{
  data: user.map(function(item) {
    return item.progress.map(progress => [progress.tasks, progress.week]);
  })
}];

console.log(this.splineChart)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to activatedRoute, like:

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    .....
) {}
```

Then

```
load() {
   const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
   if (id != null)
     this._peopleService.getPeopleById(id)
     .subscribe(
       (user: User[]) => {
         this.splineChart = [{
           data: user.map(function (item) {
             return [item.progress.tasks, item.progress.week]; 
         })}]
       },
       error => {
         console.log(error)
       }
  )
```

}

Wish, it will help you.

Comment: What's the difference? It won't work that way either.     I have a problem occurring here:     `this.splineChart = [{
           data: user.map(function (item) {
             return [item.progress.tasks, item.progress.week]; 
         })}] `